# Strip empty lines with mysql and regex

Tags: mysql

I'm importing a mysql table and a field has text with many blank lines.

I would like to use a regex to strip the blank lines.

A regex I found on SO would be something like this: '/^\s*$(?:\r\n?|\n)/gm'.

Then, I used:

```
SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE (description, '/^\s*$(?:\r\n?|\n)/gm','') as mycol FROM tableA.
```

But it does not work.
I think I'm getting it wrong on how to use regexp_replace.

Answer (score 0):

[REGEXP_REPLACE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/regexp.html#function_regexp-replace) will only work if you use MySQL 8+

Also its unclear if your trying to remove extra blank lines at beginning and end of the `description` or all of them altogether.

To simply `TRIM` the extra rows at start and end of your field and keep all formatting in between, you can use

```
SELECT TRIM(BOTH '(\r\n|\r|\n)' FROM description) FROM...
```

If your trying to remove all line breaks and simply keep the text, you can use

```
SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE(description, '(\r\n|\r|\n)', '') FROM...
```

Comment: Hi, The content field is something as when I used node with console.log in the result: 
 Inserido Por: zGeorge Vieira de Mello  Rudge\n' +
    ' \n' +
    ' \n' +
    ' TROUXE RM - APRESENTA DISCOPATIA DEGENERATIVA L5-L5 ; L5-S1\n' +
    ' \n' +
    'OSTEOPROROSE EM SEGMENTO LOMBAR MAS NÃO PODE TOMAR REMÁDIO PELO ESTOMAGO\n' +
    ' \n' +
    ' \n'     and I´d like to get rid off the empty lines

Comment: As you can see there are blank lines

Comment: Hre is other field content:    ' Inserido Por: ZJosé Fernando Rodrigues Gagliano\n' +
    '\n' +
    ' \n' +
    '\n' +
    ' \n' +
    '\n' +
    ' Em tratam. de epicondilite de cotovelo esq. há 3 meses(SIC).\n' +
    '     \n' +
    '         \n' +
    '  \n' +
    'Ainda c/ dor leve.\n' +
    '   \n' +
    '    \n' +
    '\n' +
    'Crioterapia + alongamento.\n' +
    '\n' +
    ' \n' +
    '\n' +
    ' \n' +
    '\n' +
    ' '

Comment: Into the '/n' there is some spaces before the 'here is some spaces /n' . I am showing where teere are spaces because the post get rid of them

Comment: Im not sure i totally understand you. It doesnt look like its all coming from mysql, are you manually concatenating (+) empty line breaks to your string or is that in the actual mysql description field?